# HTTP request fails with timeout

Tags: android, httprequest

I try to execute a simple http request on Android with this simple code :

```
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);  
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        return EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
```

On every device I testet yet, it works fine (Android 2.3.6 + ), but the HTC Desire ( Android 2.3.5), I tested today fails with a timeout. But this only happend on my specific url, which looks like :

```
http://api.mydomain.com/some/path/index.php?param=value+number&param2=value
```

If I try another url like :

```
http://www.google.com
```

it works, even on HTC. Did anyone had an idea, why I get a timeout only on these device/url?

Comment: Are you logging how much time it takes to perform the http call anywhere?  Is it typically running long on all devices?  

If the call cannot be optimized to run faster, perhaps you can increase the timeout limit for your call.

Comment: while debugging the test with google takes about 2 seconds, my specific url needs about 30 seconds or more till it throws an exception.

Comment: Is it normal for your call to take 30+ seconds?  If so, I think you may just have to extend the timeout.

Comment: no, normally it's done after 1-5 seconds...for example on my own device

Comment: Is your host reachable from the HTC Desire?  You could try to reach it with the browser.  E.g. I often run into this problem if I am testing against a development server on my internal network but I forget to connect to the network via wifi.

Comment: @Mike : I had the sam idea ;-), but I had a connection to the internet via device, and was able to connect to my domain via browser, only on my app it doesn't worked.

Comment: Do you send a valid response? Try to send some static response and check the header if they are missing something important.

Comment: Yeah it is valid, if I debug on my device it works, and if I call url via browser on failed device it works to

Comment: does that happen on an Emulator running 2.3.5 too?

Comment: did not tested yet, cause my emulator actually didn't support internet